# Convert UTC TIme HH:mm:ss to Device time HH:mm:ss and adding Day saving time if available

Tags: java, android, date, datetime

I Have UTC String with a format (HH: mm: ss) and I need to convert the String value into device Time in the same format (HH: mm: ss) and also adding  Day saving time if available I Have Tried to convert the UTC String to device time by this code but I am getting a 1 hour delay due to (day saving time).

```
String utcTimeString = "12:15:00"
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH: mm: ss");
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date value = formatter.parse(utcTimeString);

SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH: mm: ss"); 
dateFormatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
utcDateString = dateFormatter.format(value);
```

My Time Zone is GMT-4

Expected Output: 08:15:00;
Given Output: 07:15:00;

Comment: Could you please add the `String` along with your current and your desired output?

Comment: Which Java version are you using? Something below Java 8 or 8+? Is the time always a time at the current day?

Comment: I am using  Java8. No it is not same as the current day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Answer by deHaar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58076337/642706) is generally correct, and wisely makes use of the modern *java.time* classes. However, I would use a slightly different approach.

## tl;dr

```
OffsetDateTime.of(                           // Represent a moment as a date, a time-of-day, and an offset-from-UTC.
    LocalDate.now( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ,        // Current date as seen right now in UTC. Beware: For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone.
    LocalTime.parse( "12:15:00" ) ,          // Your specified time-of-day.
    ZoneOffset.UTC                           // An offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds, for UTC itself.
)                                            // Returns an `OffsetDateTime` object.
.atZoneSameInstant(                          // Adjust from UTC to a time zone. Same moment, different wall-clock-time.
    ZoneId.of( "America/Port_of_Spain" ) ;   // One of the many time zones that are behind UTC by four hours on that date.
)                                            // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
.toLocalTime()                               // Extract the time-of-day only, leaving behind the date and the zone.
```

## Time zone

> My Time Zone is GMT-4

Nope. That is not a time zone.

The value `GMT-4` represents merely an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset). A number of hours-minutes-seconds ahead or behind the UTC baseline.

A time zone is *much* more. A time zone has a name, and represents the history of past, present, and future changes the offset used by the people of a particular region. Therefore, a time zone is always preferable to a mere offset.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Casablanca" ) ;
```

If your time zone is currently four hours behind UTC, you must be in a time zone such as `America/Aruba`, `America/Puerto_Rico`, `America/Manaus`, `America/Martinique`, etc.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Martinique" ) ;
```

## UTC

> I Have UTC String with a format (HH: mm: ss)

Nope.

A value such as `"12:15:00"` cannot be said to be a value in UTC. Without a date, that value has no real meaning. A moment consists of three parts:

- a date,
- a time-of-day, and
- an offset/zone.

Saying "noon in UTC" only gives us 2 of the 3 parts. The date is missing.

## Today… what a concept

Perhaps you want to apply that time-of-day to the current date as seen in UTC.

```
LocalDate todayUTC = LocalDate.now( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

Just keep in mind that **for any given moment the date varies around the globe by zone**. At this very moment, the date is “tomorrow“ in Tokyo Japan while still being “yesterday” in Toledo Ohio US.

### `OffsetDateTime`

Combine all three into a [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) object: date, time-of-day, and offset/zone.

```
LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse( "12:15:00" ) ;
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.of( todayUTC , localTime, ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

### `ZonedDateTime`

Adjust from UTC to your particular time zone. Same moment, same simultaneous point on the timeline, different wall-clock time. Apply a `ZoneId` to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) object. The time zone nows about if and when [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) applies for this particular zone, and adjusts accordingly.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Martinique" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant( z ) ;
```

## Wrong approach

You should not be adding/subtracting some number of hours from a `LocalTime`. On some dates in some zones, a particular time-of-day may not exist. For example, for Daylight Saving Time, on the day of "Spring-ahead", in the United States, a time-of-day of 02:15:00 does not exist, as the clock jumps ahead from 02:00:00 to 03:00:00.

The correct approach using the `ZonedDateTime` class will automatically adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `java.time`, the modern date time API, and parse the time `String` to a moment in time, that is an `Instant`.
Then use `ZonedDateTime` objects to apply a certain time zone, which may be done in different ways, I show you one of them here:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // the source is just a time, but to correctly convert it, you need a date
    String utcTime = "12:15:00";
    // take today's date
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
    // create a parseable date time String
    String parseableDateTime = today.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE) + "T" + utcTime + "Z";
    // then create an Instant parsing the date time String
    Instant instant = Instant.parse(parseableDateTime);

    // get the ZoneId of UTC in order to have the time in UTC
    ZoneId utc = ZoneId.of("UTC");
    // do the same with your ZoneOffset of -4 Hours
    ZoneId gmtMinusFour = ZoneId.ofOffset("GMT", ZoneOffset.ofHours(-4));

    // create a UTC ZonedDateTime of the instant and the UTC ZoneID 
    ZonedDateTime utcZdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instant, utc);
    // then use that ZonedDateTime to convert it to a time with your ZoneId
    ZonedDateTime gmtMinusFourZdt = utcZdt.withZoneSameInstant(gmtMinusFour);

    // finally print both ZonedDateTimes in order to compare them
    System.out.println("UTC time is:\t\t" 
            + utcZdt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME));
    System.out.println("GMT-4 time is:\t\t"
            + gmtMinusFourZdt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME));

    // then just get the time part of the converted ZonedDateTime
    LocalTime localTime = gmtMinusFourZdt.toLocalTime();
    // and print it
    System.out.println("Converted time is:\t" 
            + localTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_TIME));
}
```

Output:

```
UTC time is:        2019-09-24T12:15:00Z[UTC]
GMT-4 time is:      2019-09-24T08:15:00-04:00[GMT-04:00]
Converted time is:  08:15:00
```

There may be better solutions, but I hope this helps anyway…

Comment: Works like a charm with SDK version above 26. but my app has min SDK version of 17 which does not support ZonedDateTime.

Comment: @koushikchaturvedula There is a backport that one can use in older Java versions, I think it would be possible to use for your app to support older API in Android, check it out, the [ThreeTen backport](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/). It provides compatibilty with java.time, but the downside is another library

Comment: I would suggest using the `with` methods rather than manipulating strings. Also, `OffsetDateTime` is more appropriate for handling values with only a mere offset (a number of hour-minutes-seconds). The `ZonedDateTime` type is for use with a time zone (a history of past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region).